# Angle between dipole moment and electric field

Tags: electric-fields, torque, dipole

I was learning the potential energy of a dipole because of torque from Halliday Resnick. In the given diagram, it said that if we move the system anticlockwise then the amount the Work that was done by the torque would be equal to $\displaystyle\int_{90}^θ-pE\sin θdθ$. Where Torque is given by $pΕ\sin θ$. Now potential at $90°$ is considered to be zero hence we get $\displaystyle U=-W=\int_{90}^θpE\sin θdθ$. So we get $U(θ)=-pE\cos θ$.

But when we move the system anticlockwise isn't the angle actually greater than $90°$. So the result we just got is for an angle greater than $90°$. So if we get an angle less than that it should come out positive as $\cos (90+θ)=-\sin θ$. Hence shouldn't it actually be $pE\sin θ$? Where have I gone wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the edit one last time. Maybe you will get it this time.

Comment: Looking at the diagram you supplied, the angle appears to less than 90 degrees.  It goes to zero as the dipole comes into alignment with the field.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
$dW=\vec\tau_{_E}\cdot d\vec\varphi>0$ when both $\vec\tau_{_E}=\vec p\times \vec E$ and $d\vec\varphi$ are in the same direction(or if constitute an acute angle), regardless of the choice of the coordinate system. Here, the work done by the electric field is **positive** in both the cases because both the torque of the field $\vec\tau_{_E}$ and the angular displacement $d\vec\varphi$ are anti-clockwise in both the cases. The only difference between the two cases is a mathematical one, the axis $\varphi$ is measured from.

Potential energy is the work done against the conservative force to move the particle slowly. Hence, the potential energy in both the cases above should be the same (**negative**) regardless of the choice of coordinate axes. This equivalence is exhibited mathematically as follows:

**CASE I:** Measuring the angle $\theta$ clockwise from the $x-$axis pointing towards the **left**.
$$U=-W_{_E}=-\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\theta_0} (\vec p \times \vec E)\cdot (d\vec\theta)=\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\theta_0} pE\sin\theta\, d\theta=-pE[\cos\theta]_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\theta_0}=-pE\cos\theta_0=-\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf E<0$$
where $|d\vec\theta|=-d\theta\circlearrowleft$, where $d\theta<0$. As a check $W_{_E}=\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\theta_0} \underbrace{(\vec p \times \vec E)\cdot (d\vec\theta)}_{\circlearrowleft\ \cdot\ \circlearrowleft}>0$.

---

**CASE II:** Measuring the angle anti-clockwise from an axis pointing towards the **right**.
$$U=-W_{_E}=-\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2+\theta_0^\prime} (\vec p \times \vec E)\cdot (d\vec\theta)=-\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2+\theta_0^\prime} pE\sin\theta\, d\theta=pE[\cos\theta]_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2+\theta_0^\prime}=pE\cos\left(\frac{\pi}2+\theta_0^\prime\right)=-pE\cos\left[\pi-\left(\frac{\pi}2+\theta_0^\prime\right)\right]=-pE\cos\theta_0=-\mathbf p\cdot\mathbf E<0$$
where $|d\vec\theta|=d\theta\circlearrowleft$, where $d\theta>0$. As a check $W_{_E}=\int_{\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}2+\theta_0^\prime} \underbrace{(\vec p \times \vec E)\cdot (d\vec\theta)}_{\circlearrowleft\ \cdot\ \circlearrowleft}>0$.

Comment: But isn't the θ the angle between them and not the angle between the axis's??

Comment: @Naruto What do you mean by "them"?

Comment: Yes but see your answer in the second case you can see that the energy is negative for an angle greater than 90. If you take 90+theta as alpha you get this, and then if is negative for 90+theta it would be positive for theta. And the result should be p-E

Comment: I think by them Naruto means p and E

Comment: @BlackThunder Sorry, I messed up. Have a look at the edit that I have made by scrutinizing each term's sign.

Comment: @SameerBaheti if torque is anticlockwise and dtheta is clockwise then work done by external is positive its not negative

Comment: @BlackThunder Nope! The dipole is moving opposite to the external torque and hence the work of external torque is negative.

Comment: @SameerBaheti U is given as negative of the work done by the torque not the external torque, the work done by torque due to electric field is negative, hence U=positive

Comment: @SameerBaheti see as you are also applying the force in the clockwise direction to move theta to clockwise, Work will be positive as displacement in theta is in the direction of the external force applied

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110591/discussion-between-blackthunder-and-sameer-baheti).